# Android Studio refactor revert all lambdas and other Java 8 features

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

I have an Android library project with

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

It uses a lot of lambdas, try with resources and etc.

How could I **downgrade** sourceCompatibility & targetCompatibility to **Java 1.6** instead?

Is there such functionality built in Android Studio IDE?

Comment: why downgrade btw. ? Why not learn how to use lambdas? :-)

Comment: @donfuxx need to use library in xamarin project that doesn't support java 8 :(

Comment: uh oh, good luck :-)

Comment: **Lambda** - not "lambada" .....

Comment: @marc_s   where do u see 'lambada'?

Comment: I corrected one occurrence in the title, one in the body .....

Comment: @marc_s sorry, didn't noticed that, autocorrection is an evil :D

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can replace the lambda by placing the cursor inside the `->` and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> then select "Replace lambda with..."

[image]

---

**You can do it on an entire file** by expanding the menu and selecting "Fix all..."

[image]

---

**You can do it on the whole project** by following the above steps, but instead click "Run inspection on..."

[image]

Select "Whole project"

[image]

Once the inspection finishes, right click on the "Lambda can be replaced..." section and select "Replace lambda with..."

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thanks for ur answer! Is there the way to do it on the whole project?

Comment: You can do it on a whole file, but I'm unaware of a way to do it on an entire project.

Comment: Thanks! Will try it out shortly :)

Comment: @OlexiiMuraviov I figured out how to do it for the whole project, check my edit.

Comment: For some reason, "Replace lambda with anonymous class" wasn't showing up as an option under ALT-ENTER.  Instead, I was able to double-press SHIFT and type in "Replace Lambda"